# Setting validations on textfields

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I m doing a registration form and if any of the textfield is left empty then I want to validate it .But I dont want to display a regular UIAlertView when textfield is empty.
Can I display any redcoloured star marked or anything else beside particular textField?

How can I validate to check for emailId pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can show a red coloured image or label with * text on it and you can hide and show it like wise .

To validate email you can use the following code

```
 +(BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) email 
 {
      NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]";
      NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
      BOOL isValid = [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
      return isValid;
 }
```

Comment: Can I know what is this{2,4}?

Answer (score 2):

You can set text with red color in your `textField`

```
if ([yourTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        yourTextField.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
        yourTextField.text=@"Value Required";
    }
```

set delegate of your textField in .h file

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` you can change your textField color

If you are setting * in your textField then do this

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"*"])
    {
        textField.text=@"";
        textField.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

Or you can make a label beside your `textField` and hide it initially and show when ever you needed.

**Validation for email**

```
- (BOOL)isValidEmailId:(NSString*)email
{

    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

Comment: I have added a label and set its text to * and hiding/showing it accordingly.When I left textfield empty * will display.But how can I remove it as I start entering charaters in it?I have set txtemail.delegate=self;and did like this:- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    lblvalidateemail.hidden=YES;
    
}But the * is not getting hidden.textFieldDidBeginEditing is not getting called.I have created textfields in interface builder.Can u please tell me how?

Comment: hi just set UITextFieldDelegate in your .h class

Comment: Rajneesh I suggest u to be not aggressive and let me tell u that I have already marked the answer by the time u gave the answer.But because you have also given appropriate answer I upvoted without leaving as it is.

Comment: i gave you answer on time..i was not late.. fir bhi thk h thk h, 2,3 baar dekh liya h mene aisa hote hue..:P

Comment: See if u gave it on time why wouldn't I have marked it..??I dont show any differences here because nobody knows none and everybody is here to increase their knowledge.

Comment: but i know you, and your name...:P

Answer (score 1):

Validation for email field:

```
- (BOOL)EmailValidationL:(NSString *)email
{
    NSString *emailRegEx =@"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"
    @"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
    @"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
    @"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
    @"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
    @"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
    @"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";

    NSPredicate *regExPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
    a= [regExPredicate evaluateWithObject:email];
    return a;
}
```

And for checking it do like below:

```
if (![self EmailValidationL:emailtxt.text])
    {

        mailAlert  =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                              message:@"Email Field Is Not Valid"
                                             delegate:nil
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
        [mailAlert show];
        [mailAlert release];
    }
```

Comment: In .h file declare this: BOOL a;

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you get many solution for Email.

so lets go for star. You may have many way for this let me give two of them

1. Add hidden UIImageView where you want to show start and make is visible when use left it empty
2. use [UIView addSubView:UIImageView] to show start when you want to show.

If u want to show normal * in red color you can use UILabel instead of UIImageView.

I use following to validate email:

```
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

if(![emailTest evaluateWithObject:txtMail.text])
{
  //Your code if wrong email
}
```

All the best....

Comment: Please dont just downvote give a good reason so I can improve.

Comment: Can I know what is this{2,4}?

Comment: ya it is length after "." like .co is 2 .com is 3

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

First, take simple label in XIB with simple text & color:

```
-(void)DidLoad
{
   -----
   lbl.hidden = YES;
   -----
}

Attributes:
text = "* email invalid"
color = "red"

Or whatever you like.
```

'textDidEndEditing' method.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if(textField == txtEmail)
   {
      if(![txtEmail.text isEqualToString:@""])
      {
         bool chk = [self validateEmail:txtEmail.text];
         if(!chk)
         {
            lbl.hidden = NO;
            lbl.text = @"email invalid";
         }
         else
            lbl.hidden = YES;
      }
      else
      {
         lbl.hidden = NO;
         lbl.text = @"* required";
      }
   }
}
```

Email Validation

```
+(BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) email 
{
  NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
  NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
  BOOL isValid = [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
  return isValid;
}
```

Comment: I have added a label and set its text to * and hiding/showing it accordingly.When I left textfield empty * will display.But how can I remove it as I start entering charaters in it?I have set txtemail.delegate=self;and did like this:- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { lblvalidateemail.hidden=YES; }But the * is not getting hidden.textFieldDidBeginEditing is not getting called.I have created textfields in interface builder.Can u please tell me how?

Comment: Bind textfield with delegate. And please check whether label is bind or not. Put validation in 'DidEndEditing' as I explained.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly Shashank Kulshrestha has given nice answer of validating email . Now if you want show some thing for indicating the invalid or empty input do following to that text field. It will show red edges.
1.Add QuartzCore framework.
2.Import #import 
3.add following code :

```
if (textfield==empty || invalid)
{
    textField.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
    textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
    textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

}
```

Comment: why down vote ? whoever down voted just take a effort to read a question.Can I display any redcoloured star marked or anything else beside particular textField? and put a comment for down vote .